# Send dictionary object to thread class using signal

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt5

I use PyQt5 and Python2.7

I have UIWidget class, PlayStreaming class and Thread class.

Once a button from UIWidget is pressed and then dictionary object from PlayStreaming is sent to Thread class.

If I remove 'QVariantMap', I can receive Button click signal, but I can't send data.

How can I solve the problem?

My whole code is as follow.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QInputDialog
import cv2
import time
import face_recognition.api as face_recognition

class Thread(QtCore.QThread):    
    changePixmap = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtGui.QImage)
    updateStatus = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    scaled_size = QtCore.QSize(640, 480)          
    curScale=1.0
    facearray=[]
    dim=(640,480) 
    processedImage=[]
    def run(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)
        cap.set(3,1280);
        cap.set(4,1024);
        time.sleep(2)
        self.maxHeight=cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
        self.maxScale=self.maxHeight/480.0        
        while True:
            ret, frame = cap.read()                  
            if ret:
                r=1                
                rescaleSize=int(480*self.curScale)                              
                if(frame.shape[0] > 480 and frame.shape[1] > 640):
                    r = rescaleSize / float(frame.shape[0])
                    self.dim = (int(frame.shape[1] * r), rescaleSize)
                    processedImage=cv2.resize(frame, self.dim, fx=0.0, fy=0.0)
                    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(processedImage)
                    if(len(face_locations) > 0):
                        encodefaces(facelocs)
                else:
                    processedImage=frame.copy()
                    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(processedImage)
                    if(len(face_locations) > 0):
                        encodefaces(facelocs)
                for face_location in face_locations:  
                    top, right, bottom, left = face_location
                    cv2.rectangle(frame,(int(right/r),int(top/r)),(int(left/r),int(bottom/r)),(0,255,0),2)
                rgbImage = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                convertToQtFormat = QtGui.QImage(rgbImage.data, rgbImage.shape[1], rgbImage.shape[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)                
                p = convertToQtFormat.scaled(self.scaled_size, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
                self.changePixmap.emit(p)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QSize)
    def scaled(self, scaled_size):
        self.scaled_size = scaled_size 

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def scaleup(self):
        self.curScale = self.curScale + 0.1
        if self.curScale > self.maxScale:
            self.curScale = self.maxScale
        self.updateStatus.emit('Cur scale:'+str(self.dim))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def scaledown(self):
        self.curScale = self.curScale - 0.1
        if self.curScale < 1.0:
            self.curScale = 1.0
        self.updateStatus.emit('Cur scale:'+str(self.dim))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot('QVariantMap')
    def getfacestorecognize(self, clickedInfos):
        facearray.append(clickedInfos)
        print(clickedInfos['x']+' '+clickedInfos['y']+' '+clickedInfos['name'])

    def encodefaces(self, facelocs):
        if(len(self.facearray) > 0):
            for face in facearray:
               r=(self.scaled_size[0]/self.dim[0])
               x=int(face['x'])*r
               y=int(face['y'])*r
               #for loc in facelocs:


class PlayStreaming(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    reSize = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QSize)
    scaleupSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    scaledownSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    transferFaceInfosSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()#'QVariantMap'    

    def __init__(self):
        super(PlayStreaming, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.mousePressEvent = self.showDialog

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QImage)
    def setImage(self, image):
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image))

    def initUI(self):
        # create a label
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)        
        th = Thread(self)
        th.changePixmap.connect(self.setImage)
        th.updateStatus.connect(self.handle_status_message)
        self.scaleupSignal.connect(th.scaleup)
        self.scaledownSignal.connect(th.scaledown)
        self.transferFaceInfosSignal.connect(th.getfacestorecognize)
        self.reSize.connect(th.scaled)
        th.start()
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.label, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.reSize.emit(self.size())

    def showDialog(self, event): 
        x = event.pos().x()
        y = event.pos().y()
        facedata={"x": str(x),  "y": str(y),  "name": ''}
        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Name input dialog', 
            'Enter name:')        
        if (ok and str(text)!=''):
            facedata['name']=str(text)
            self.transferFaceInfosSignal.emit(facedata)

    def handle_status_message(self, message):
        self.window().set_status_message(message)    


class UIWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UIWidget, self).__init__(parent)        
        # Initialize tab screen
        self.tabs = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.tab1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        # Add tabs
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1, "Face")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab2, "Human")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab3, "Vehicle")

        self.display = PlayStreaming()
        # Create first tab
        self.createGridLayout()
        self.tab1.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.tab1.layout.addWidget(self.display, stretch=1)
        self.tab1.layout.addWidget(self.horizontalGroupBox)
        self.tab1.setLayout(self.tab1.layout)

        # Add tabs to widget
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.tabs)

    def createGridLayout(self):
        self.horizontalGroupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("")
        self.horizontalGroupBox.setStyleSheet("QGroupBox{ background-color: red; border: none;}")  
        hlay1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.TestButton=QtWidgets.QPushButton('Test')
        hlay1.addWidget(self.TestButton) 
        self.RunButton=QtWidgets.QPushButton('Run')
        hlay1.addWidget(self.RunButton) 
        self.ScaleUpButton=QtWidgets.QPushButton('ScaleUp')
        self.ScaleUpButton.clicked.connect(self.display.scaleupSignal)
        hlay1.addWidget(self.ScaleUpButton) 
        self.ScaleDownButton=QtWidgets.QPushButton('ScaleDown')
        self.ScaleDownButton.clicked.connect(self.display.scaledownSignal)
        hlay1.addWidget(self.ScaleDownButton) 
        hlay1.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton('Reset'))

        hlay2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        hlay2.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton('Set Faces')) 
        hlay2.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton('FacePose'))
        hlay2.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton('Gender')) 
        hlay2.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton('Age'))
        self.RecognizeButton=QtWidgets.QPushButton('Recognize')
        self.RecognizeButton.clicked.connect(self.display.transferFaceInfosSignal)
        hlay2.addWidget(self.RecognizeButton)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()        
        layout.addLayout(hlay1)
        layout.addLayout(hlay2)
        self.horizontalGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

class App(QMainWindow): 
    def __init__(self):
        super(App,self).__init__()
        self.title = 'FaceHumanVehicle'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 1000
        self.height = 800   
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.form_widget = UIWidget(self) 
        self.statusBar().showMessage('') 
        self.setCentralWidget(self.form_widget) 
        self.show()

    def set_status_message(self, message):
        return self.statusBar().showMessage(message) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: remove `self.RecognizeButton.clicked.connect(self.display.transferFaceInfosSignal)` and please provide a [mcve]

Comment: You have to connect the signal transferFaceInfosSignal to the encodefaces slot, the button has nothing to do in this case, do you think that the button has the information ?, then no, the signal will be emited when necessary.

Comment: what time do you call showDialog?

Comment: @batuman Is the button supposed to show the dialog, which then creates and sends the `facedata`? Otherwise, where does the button get the `facedata` from? It's also not clear where `showDialog` is supposed to get the `event` argument from. Please explain much more clearly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @ekhumoro I have updated whole code. No button is to send face data to thread class.

Comment: @eyllanesc I have attached whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you want to send the data when you press the button, so the slot connecting to the button should emit the signal, not connect to the signal. For this the data that I see is filled in `mousePressEvent` must be a member of the class, in this case the logic is to save the position when the image is pressed, and when the button is pressed a dialogue will be opened, a name will be established and the data will be sent.

```
class PlayStreaming(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    reSize = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QSize)
    scaleupSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    scaledownSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    transferFaceInfosSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal('QVariantMap') # <--- +++

    def __init__(self):
        super(PlayStreaming, self).__init__()
        self.facedata = {"x": "", "y": "", "name": ""} # <--- +++
        self.initUI()
        # self.mousePressEvent = self.showDialog <--- ---

    # ...

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.facedata["x"] = str(event.pos().x())
        self.facedata["y"] = str(event.pos().y())
        self.showDialog()
        super(PlayStreaming, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def showDialog(self): 
        text, ok = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Name input dialog', 'Enter name:')        
        if ok and text:
            self.facedata['name']= text

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def send_signal(self)
        if self.facedata["name"]:
            self.transferFaceInfosSignal.emit(self.facedata)

class UIWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget): 
    # ...
    def createGridLayout(self):
        # ...
        self.RecognizeButton.clicked.connect(self.display.send_signal)
        # ...
```

On the other hand the signals and slot support all native python types like dict, so you can replace `'QVariantMap'` with `dict`.

Comment: mousePressEvent is working well. The problem is that when I click, showDialog is not called.